# mysql group by and order by with limit query

Tags: mysql

mysql table structure is as follows

```
cmpid cmpname empid empname join-date
    1     xxx    21      p        18
    2     abc    13      q        10
    1     xxx    20      r         9      
    2     abc    19      s        21
    2     abc    18      t        20
    1     xxx    19      u         1
```

I want result as per format

```
cmpid cmpname empid empname join-date
    2     abc    19      s         21
    2     abc    18      t         20

    1     xxx    21      p         18
    1     xxx    20      r          9
```

means which ever companies has any new emp. then it return that company first with first two joined emp info. and then other compnies with same format.

means order on join date and group on cmpname with 2 people info

If any one knows please reply

Thanks

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Its bit confusing.

Comment: I want records sorted on join date and each company with ony 2 records and company which has join latest return first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split that table into two different tables, employees and companies, with another table to join them together. With your current structure most things you want to do will be impossible.

I strongly recommend reading up on the rules of database normalisation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
select c.cmpid, c.cmpname, e.empid, e.empname, e.join-date
from company c
inner join employee e on (c.cmpid = e.cmpid)
group by c.cmpid, e.emp_id 
order by e.join-date
```

Comment: thanks for reply but there are not two table it's single table . but to select companies such that which has latest new emp join and give 2 records for each company in sorted order with group on company